# How to copy images from GHCR to ACR

Tags: azure, github-actions, azure-container-registry, acr, ghcr

Looking for an example in GitHub actions workflow to clone a specifc image name by commit SHA from GHCR (GitHub registry) to ACR (Azure registry) with a need to copy all the tags and labels from the source repository to the target.

At the moment, I'm using Docker pull and push commands, but didn't find a way to fetch all the tags for given image sha from GHCR.

Appreciate your help,

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**I tried in my environment and got beow results:**

To copy **`Github container registry to azure container registry`**, You can use the following this command.

**Command:**

```
az login
az acr login -n < your acr container registry >

az acr import \
  --name <container registry > \
  --source <ghcr.io/< username >/image:latest \
  --username <Git-hub RegistryUsername> \
  --password <Git-hub RegistryPassword>
```

**Console:**

[image]

**Portal:**

[image]

**For more reference:**

[Import container images - Azure Container Registry | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-import-images?tabs=azure-cli)